# Mysql query multiple inner join and left join

Tags: mysql

this is my database schema

student table:

```
studentid (PK)   |studentname 

1                |A
```

class table:

```
classid (PK)     |classname    

1                |Math
2                |Science
```

teach table:

```
teachid  (PK)    |  classid   |   studentid 

1                |  1         |   1
2                |  2         |   1
```

quiz table:

```
quizid  (PK)     |classid     | quizname

1                |1           | mathquiz
2                |2           | science quiz
```

quizscore table:

```
quizscoreid(PK)  | quizid     |studentid   |score
1                | 1          |1           |60
2                | 2          |1           |0
```

and this is my sql query that i use :

```
SELECT
    quiz.quizid,
    teach.classid,
    student.studentname,
    student.studentid,
    quizscore.score,
    quiz.quizname,
    class.classname
FROM teach 
INNER JOIN class
    ON teach.classid = class.classid
INNER JOIN student
    ON teach.studentid = student.studentid
INNER JOIN quiz
    ON quiz.classid = '1'
LEFT JOIN quizscore
    ON teach.studentid = quizscore.studentid
WHERE
    teach.classid='1' AND
    teach.classid = quiz.classid AND
    quiz.quizid = '1'
ORDER BY studentid ASC
```

and its output like this:

```
studentid   |quizid    |classid    | studentname  |classname   | quizname   | score
1           |    1     |1          |  A           |Math        | mathquiz   | 60
1           |    1     |1          |  A           |Science     | mathquiz   | 0
```

while im expecting like this:

```
studentid   | quizid     |classid    | studentname  |classname   | quizname   | score
1           | 1          |1          |  A           |Math        | mathquiz   | 60
```

please help me correct my sql query

Comment: What is the logic by which that `Science` record is getting dropped?

Comment: Did you mean for your `INNER JOIN quiz` to use a value in the table instead of a hard-coded value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i need to only get mathquiz score which have id class 1 and quiz id 1 but the sciencequiz score get returned too

Comment: @david no, im already using variable for that. this is just example database

Comment: So do you immediately see the problem here?  You need to provide _additional_ logic to rule out the `Science` record, because your current criteria aren't getting the job done.

Comment: quis? Quid est quis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two joins missing I found, I have made the correction in SQL. Try it, hope you will get expected result.

```
SELECT
    quiz.quizid,
    teach.classid,
    student.studentname,
    student.studentid,
    quizscore.score,
    quiz.quizname,
    class.classname
FROM teach 
INNER JOIN class
    ON teach.classid = class.classid
INNER JOIN student
    ON teach.studentid = student.studentid
INNER JOIN quiz
    ON quiz.classid = tech.classid
LEFT JOIN quizscore
    ON (teach.studentid = quizscore.studentid
    and quiz.quizid = quizscore.quizid)
WHERE
    teach.classid='1' AND
    teach.classid = quiz.classid AND
    quiz.quizid = '1' and
    quiz.classid = '1'
ORDER BY studentid ASC
```

Comment: Even you can remove one of the "classid" conditions from SQL, that is not necessary. All the bset!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
A.studentid, 
D.quizid, 
A.classid, 
C.studentname, 
B.classname, 
D.quizname, 
E.score
FROM
teach A 
LEFT JOIN class B ON A.classid=B.classid
LEFT JOIN student C ON A.studentid=C.studentid
LEFT JOIN quiz D ON A.classid=D.classid
LEFT JOIN quizscore E ON D.quizid=E.quizid AND E.studentid=A.studentid
WHERE 
A.studentid=1 AND 
D.quizid=1 AND  
A.classid=1;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c1ea/1)